# Disable config edit in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to disable the configApi in solr and i read it in a blog stating that "Disable the ConfigAPI if not in use, by running Solr with the system property disable.configEdit=true" .Can someone please explain a little bit on how actually we do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set system properties in the Solr startup file. There's usually a parameter named `SOLR_OPTS`, where you can add `-Ddisable.configEdit=true`. You should also be able to set this in the shell before starting solr with `export SOLR_OPTS=....`.

To preserve any values coming from the shell, you should use `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Ddisable.configEdit=true"` when editing the Solr startup file.

From the example solr.in.sh bundled with Solr:

```
# Anything you add to the SOLR_OPTS variable will be included in the java
# start command line as-is, in ADDITION to other options. If you specify the
# -a option on start script, those options will be appended as well. Examples:
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=3000"
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoCommit.maxTime=60000"
#SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. should i edit the solr startup file as SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Ddisable.configEdit=true OR SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.disable.configEdit=true ?

Comment: I think the first one is correct, as the `solr` prefix only was useful back when Solr usually ran together with other applications on the same app server.

Comment: the main aim of disabling the config api is to stop viewing the solrconfig via api , right ? If iam wrong, can you please brief me the importance of config api ?

Comment: The config API is used for updating the configuration through the API. It's not directly related to the `solrconfig.xml` file - the config API writes its own configuration file that takes precedence over the `solrconfig.xml` file in what it configures. My guess is that it won't disable _retrieval_ of the configuration, it's named `disable.configEdit` after all (**edit** being the key word). You might want to look into [Solr Authorization](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line in solr.in.cmd and restarting SOLR worked for me,

```
set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Ddisable.configEdit=true
```

We could also validate if the Config API is disabled by executing the following curl command which should result in 403 Forbidden Error,

```
curl https://localhost:8983/solr/<core_name>/config -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{'set-user-property' : {'variable_name':'some_value'}}"
```